# When applying for a USA B1/B2 visa do I need to declare previous L1 or H1 rejections in older/ expired passports?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas, visa-rejections

If I had a history of L1 or H1 rejections 10+ years ago (i.e. 2 passports before my current one) do I still need to mention those while applying for a tourist visa for USA today?

Will CEAC have a track of data so much farther in the past? Also please note that the rejections were before any formal appearance for interviews i.e. rejected at initial processing stage due to incorrect data or refused due to lack of experience for that visa category.

I don't know if mentioning those earlier declinations will have a negative impact on getting tourist visa processed. Hence wondering if it is better to ignore mentioning them at all.

Comment: **Attention, close voters**. This question is about applying for non-immigrant visas. It is completely on-topic, here. Why are you voting to close?

Answer (score 21):

Refusals don't expire, least of all in any way that has anything to do with passports.  Refusals are on *you the person*.  If you were a dual citizen and carried two nations' passports, you'd have to disclose refusals that happened there, too.

However, old refusals, especially over routine stuff like lack of adequate paperwork or youth/lack of ties to the community, hold less weight simply due to their age, and no weight at all if the underlying conditions no longer apply.

Whereas, new deception is *right now*.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you should mention them. Not mentioning them may have a negative impact on your credibility should they find out. L1 and H1 refusals 10+ years ago should not have any impact on a B1/B2 application.